# What's the theory behind using thin spouted kettles when making drip/pour over coffee

Tags: drip-brew, pour-over

I own a drip coffee pot:
[image]

and one of the other things you can buy is a [thin spouted kettle](http://www.hario.jp/product/list.php?middelclass=3) which is used for pouring water one to the grounds.

What is the theory behind this?

Does the rate of water delivery/flow just agitate the suspension of coffee/water in a way that is better?

I also see such items being used in coffee shops too so would really like an expert's summation on this.

Comment: This seems to be about pour-overs rather than drip coffee.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith we call it drip coffee in UK and in Japan

Comment: interesting, in the US drip coffee specifically refers to traditional coffee brewing machines where water is heated to boiling and then dripped over the grounds and filter and then after extraction drifts into a pot below (like an office coffee pot or one in a greasy spoon).

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith we call those filter coffees, to be honest drip coffee is a Japanese term but I have seen it used in some UK espresso shops it's a fairly recent-ish thing here but has been around for a while in Japan and is very popular there

Comment: I'll post a meta about it so we can come to a consensus about which term we will use as a community and then set that as the description in the tag wiki.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith sure I can understand the confusion here, I can attach a picture if I can find a royalty free one

Comment: Go for it, I just posted the meta question about it.

Comment: We also generally refer to a "thin spouted kettle" as a "gooseneck kettle"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By having a thin spout, you can more finely control the flow rate and where the water lands.    When making pour-over coffee, you want to control the water level in the cone to control the brew time and evenly extract coffee.  Also, water needs to be poured carefully onto the middle of the cone so that the water doesn't run down the side of the cone without touching the coffee grounds.